# How to specify multiple 404 causes in OpenAPI (Swagger)?

Tags: swagger, swagger-2.0, openapi

I'm defining a path for a nested resource (content belonging to a delivery).  If the client gets a 404 it could either because the delivery ID was not found, or the delivery did not contain any content of the specified type.

How do I model that using OpenAPI (YAML)?

I've got this right now...

```yaml
 paths:
  '/deliveries/{id}/content/articles':
    get:
      summary: Retrieves articles from a delivery
      description: Retrieves all articles from a single delivery
      [...]
      responses:
        '200':
          description: articles found
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/Article'
        '404':
          description: delivery not found
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/Error'
        '404':
          description: delivery did not contain any articles
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/Error'
```

... but when I save the JSON from the Swagger Editor, it dropps the all 404 responses except the last one ("delivery did not contain any articles").

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Multiple response types per status code are not allowed in OpenAPI/Swagger 2.0, but are supported in OpenAPI 3.0 [by using `oneOf`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47453822/113116).

In OpenAPI 2.0, you can only have a single schema for a 404 response:

```yaml
      responses:
        '404':
          description: delivery not found, or delivery did not contain any articles
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/Error'

...
definitions:
  Error:
    type: object
    properties:
      status:
        type: integer
      type:
        type: string
      message:
        type: string
```

where the `Error` payload can be, say:

```javascript
{
  "status": 404,
  "type": "DeliveryNotFoundError",
  "message": "delivery not found"
}
```

```javascript
{
  "status": 404,
  "type": "NoArticlesInDeliveryError",
  "message": "delivery did not contain any articles"
}
```

Comment: Could you show the actual YAML definition of Error please?

Comment: Added the Error definition.

Comment: This does not answer the question. The question was how to specify multiple responses for the same code, with the same response type, but with different descriptions. See the example in the question. The only difference between the two 404s is the description, the response type is identical.