# How to define different responses for same HTTP status code in OpenAPI (Swagger)?

Tags: swagger, openapi

I'm writing an OpenAPI spec for an existing API. This API returns status 200 for both success and failure, but with a different response structure.

For example, in the signup API, if the user signed up successfully, the API sends status 200 with the following JSON:

```
{
    "result": true,
    "token": RANDOM_STRING
}
```

And if there is a duplicated user, the API also sends status 200, but with the following JSON:

```
{
    "result": false,
    "errorCode": "00002", // this code is duplicated error
    "errorMsg": "duplicated account already exist"
}
```

In this case, how to define the response?

Comment: any specific reason you don't use different response codes for different responses?

Comment: I am build document for already existing api. I can't edit api because there are many apis and now application uses the api.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to specify multiple 404 causes in swagger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40640669/how-to-specify-multiple-404-causes-in-swagger)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

This is possible in OpenAPI 3.0 but not in 2.0.

OpenAPI 3.0 supports `oneOf` for specifying alternate schemas for the response. You can also add multiple response `examples`, such as successful and failed responses. Swagger UI supports multiple `examples` since v. 3.23.0.

```yaml
openapi: 3.0.0
...

paths:
  /something:
    get:
      responses:
        '200':
          description: Result
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                oneOf:
                  - $ref: '#/components/schemas/ApiResultOk'
                  - $ref: '#/components/schemas/ApiResultError'
              examples:
                success:
                  summary: Example of a successful response
                  value:
                    result: true
                    token: abcde12345
                error:
                  summary: Example of an error response
                  value:
                    result: false
                    errorCode: "00002"
                    errorMsg: "duplicated account already exist"

components:
  schemas:
    ApiResultOk:
      type: object
      properties:
        result:
          type: boolean
          enum: [true]
        token:
          type: string
      required:
        - result
        - token
    ApiResultError:
      type: object
      properties:
        result:
          type: boolean
          enum: [false]
        errorCode:
          type: string
          example: "00002"
        errorMsg:
          type: string
          example: "duplicated account already exist"
```

In OpenAPI/Swagger 2.0, you can only use a single schema per response code, so the most you can do is define the varying fields as optional and document their usage in the model `description` or operation `description`.

```yaml
swagger: "2.0"
...

definitions:
  ApiResult:
    type: object
    properties:
      result:
        type: boolean
      token:
        type: string
      errorCode:
        type: string
      errorMsg:
        type: string
    required:
      - result
```

Comment: this is not being rendered properly in the swaggerhub and other swagger file renderers. It doesn't reference the Proper Schema in the specific response code it was declared. It just shows a blank response and not using the schema declared,

Comment: @iamjoshua Currently Swagger UI [does not](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/3803) generate examples for `oneOf` and `anyOf` models, but you can work around this by providing a custom `example` or `examples` - as in my answer. If there are issues with other renderer tools, consider filing bug reports with the tooling vendors.