# How to define two different responses for same Response code with 302 Redirect?

Tags: swagger, openapi

I'm trying to set two different responses of 302 in out API since our API redirects to a different Endpoint depending on the request sent. I'm current using Open API ver 3.0.1. How do I do that?

> I basically just want two different Location Headers for the 302
>   redirect describing how why the particular Location header is returned. Or have two same 302 response codes

[image: I basically just want two different Location Headers for the 302 redirect describing how why the particular Location header is returned]

[I was following this older thread.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47447403/how-to-define-different-responses-for-same-http-status-code-in-openapi-swagger) But it doesn't correctly reference the two different Location headers in the actual API Endpoint, and instead just shows a blank Location header.

My Code snippet is:

```
  responses:
    '200':
      description: 'Sample 200 Response'
    '302':
      description: 'Sample 302 Responses. See <302ExpiredRefreshTokenstring> & <302ExpiredUserRefreshTokenstring> schemas for reference'
      headers:
        Location:
          schema:
            oneOf:
              - $ref: '#/components/schemas/302ExpiredRefreshToken'
              - $ref: '#/components/schemas/302ExpiredUserRefreshToken'
```

And the schema is:

```
components:
  schemas:
    302ExpiredRefreshToken:
      type: string
      example: 'www.<UIEndpoint>/ref-login?SessionId=d3fe5c6959ae0ce502d6027a7693c3ebe4543f51a878d60004e1331723fc0187&redirect_uri=https://www.lazada.com.ph&state=sample_state_54321&refresh_token=sCY2O0kev5Ic516A1INnQwRc8D1hbuOJ&BillerCode=00494&UserId=JBC_28'
      description: Redirect URI if Refresh Token (FinTech) has already expired.
    302ExpiredUserRefreshToken:
      type: string
      example: 'www.<UIEndpoint>/cpw-login?SessionId=d3fe5c6959ae0ce502d6027a7693c3ebe4543f51a878d60004e1331723fc0187&redirect_uri=https://www.lazada.com.ph&state=sample_state_54321&refresh_token=sCY2O0kev5Ic516A1INnQwRc8D1hbuOJ&BillerCode=00494&UserId=JBC_28'
  description: Redirect URI if User Refresh Token (DigiFi) has already expired. This could be triggered even if the Refresh Token (FinTech) has not expired yet.
```

Adding multiple examples doesn't work either as it doesn't show the multiple examples, instead it's just a blank

```
headers:
            Location:
              schema:
                type: string
              examples: 
                'test1':
                  value: 'value1'
                'test2':
                  value: 'value2'
              description: 'Description of Location Header'
```

But the Multiple examples for a header work when placed on the request paramters as I added examples in the request like this.

```
 parameters:
          name: Location
          in: header
          examples:       
            test1:         
              value: 'value2'   
              summary: 'summary 1'
            test2: 
              value: 'value 1'  
              summary: 'summary 2'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need for multiple schemas for the `Location` header because the data type is the same in both cases - `type: string`. Instead, add multiple `examples` of the header value:

```yaml
      responses:
        ...
        '302':
          description: Some token has expired... Clients should follow the `Location` header to refresh the token.
          headers:
            Location:
              description: URI where the client can refresh the expired token.
              schema:
                type: string
                format: uri  # Optional - use if the Location header is an absolute URI, starting with http(s)://
              examples:
                302ExpiredRefreshToken:
                  description: Redirect URI if Refresh Token (FinTech) has already expired
                  value: 'www.<UIEndpoint>/ref-login?SessionId=d3fe5c6959ae0ce502d6027a7693c3ebe4543f51a878d60004e1331723fc0187&redirect_uri=https://www.lazada.com.ph&state=sample_state_54321&refresh_token=sCY2O0kev5Ic516A1INnQwRc8D1hbuOJ&BillerCode=00494&UserId=JBC_28'
                302ExpiredUserRefreshToken:
                  description: >-
                    Redirect URI if User Refresh Token (DigiFi) has already expired.
                    This could be triggered even if the Refresh Token (FinTech) has not expired yet.
                  value: 'www.<UIEndpoint>/cpw-login?SessionId=d3fe5c6959ae0ce502d6027a7693c3ebe4543f51a878d60004e1331723fc0187&redirect_uri=https://www.lazada.com.ph&state=sample_state_54321&refresh_token=sCY2O0kev5Ic516A1INnQwRc8D1hbuOJ&BillerCode=00494&UserId=JBC_28'
```

But since you use Swagger UI, please note that it currently does not display `examples` in response headers. Follow this issue for updates: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/5432

Comment: I already tried putting this (see updated question), the example values ares till blank. I am already using SwaggerHub which has a Swagger UI version of 3.25.0, while the changes for support for multiple examples in headers was promoted on Swagger UI ver.  3.23.0. But I tried testing the multiple examples in the request parameters, and it is working, but it is not working when placed in the headers of Responses.

Comment: Multiple `examples` in _response headers_ are NOT supported yet - even though they are supported in other places. I linked to the corresponding issue at the end of my answer. This is also mentioned in [SwaggerHub documentation](https://app.swaggerhub.com/help/openapi-3-support).

Comment: noted, thx. turns out I can't document properly our APIs responses then with this limitation that is not yet being fixed.