# Multi return type with different headers in OpenAPI3

Tags: openapi

In OpenApi 3 I can specify multiple return schema for the same status code.

As an example: given the endpoint `/something` and it can either return an `ApiResultOk` or `ApiResultError`.

(The example if from https://stackoverflow.com/a/47453822/3430316)

```
openapi: 3.0.0
paths:
  /something:
    get:
      responses:
        '200':
          description: Result
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                oneOf:
                  - $ref: '#/components/schemas/ApiResultOk'
                  - $ref: '#/components/schemas/ApiResultError'
components:
  schemas:
    ApiResultOk:
      type: object
      properties:
        result:
          type: boolean
          enum: [true]
        token:
          type: string
      required:
        - result
        - token
    ApiResultError:
      type: object
      properties:
        result:
          type: boolean
          enum: [false]
        errorCode:
          type: string
        errorMsg:
          type: string
```

Is it possible to specify different headers for the related schemas?

(As a workaround, headers can be optional with the description when it is provided.)

Comment: Why are you returning errors as 200? Errors should be 4xx. Is this an existing API you have no control over?

Comment: It is just a silly example. The focus is on the feasibility, not on the example. Let's imagine you have only one endpoint to serve all your responses and it always returns OK, but the error handling is in the body, however, you want to add Cookie header when it's an ApiResultOk